# Error 400 when Alexa skill is called

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an Alexa skill that responds with the value of Bitcoin in USD using the [Pylexa](https://github.com/patricksmith/pylexa) Python module, but every time I call it on Amazon's online skill tester, I get the following error:

```
There was an error calling the remote endpoint, which returned HTTP 400 : BAD REQUEST
```

Trying on my local machine, I get this error:

```
[400] Cert chain URL not valid.
```

What could be the issue? The code is deployed on a Heroku server, if that helps. My code is below, if that helps (I used similar code in another skill and it worked):

```
import json
import os
import requests

from flask import Flask

from pylexa.app import alexa_blueprint
from pylexa.intent import handle_intent
from pylexa.app import handle_launch_request
from pylexa.response import PlainTextSpeech


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['app_id'] = os.getenv('ALEXA_APP_ID')
app.register_blueprint(alexa_blueprint)

@handle_intent('GetBTC')
def handle_info_intent(request):
    try:
        print('Debug: ' + str(request.slots))
        btcValue = requests.get('http://api.coindesk.com/v2/bpi/currentprice.json').json()['bpi']['USD']['rate']
        print(btcValue)
        return PlainTextSpeech("Currently, Bitcoin is worth " + btcValue + " dollars.")
    except:
        return PlainTextSpeech("I don't know.")


@handle_intent('A')
@handle_launch_request
def handle_start_message(request):
    try:
        print("New launch!")
        btcValue = requests.get('http://api.coindesk.com/v2/bpi/currentprice.json').json()['bpi']['USD']['rate']
        print(btcValue)
        return PlainTextSpeech("Currently, Bitcoin is worth " + btcValue + " dollars.")
    except:
        return PlainTextSpeech("I don't know.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Intent schema:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "BTC",
          "type": "CURRENCY"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "GetBTC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the endpoint? Is the SSL certificate configured correctly?

Comment: The endpoint is [https://echo-btc.herokuapp.com](https://echo-btc.herokuapp.com). It uses a wildcard cert from Heroku, which I had no issues using before.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue wasn't with the code, but with Amazon's Alexa skill testing tools.

[The Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUvoa.png)